# How to count make a list of string values and count how many times it repeats in the given file

Tags: c#

I have a txt. file of films with their name, release year, genre, studio, director, main actor, and earnings. It's all in a list, and I need to print out all the different studios and how many films each studio have produced

```
static Dictionary<string, int> GetFrequencies(List<string> stud)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (string FilmStudio in stud)
            {
                if (result.TryGetValue(FilmStudio, out int count))
                {
                    // Increase existing value.
                    result[FilmStudio] = count + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // New value, set to 1.
                    result.Add(FilmStudio, 1);
                }
            }
            // Return the dictionary.
            return result;
        }
```

It does not count the number of films each studio made, but instead, it assigns the value (1).
I am using this function to print out the data

```
void DisplaySortedFrequencies(string fv,Dictionary<string, int> frequencies)
        {
            using (var fr = new StreamWriter(File.Open(fv, FileMode.Append),
            Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                
                {
                    // Order pairs in dictionary from high to low frequency.
                    var sorted = from pair in frequencies
                                 orderby pair.Value descending
                                 select pair;

                    // Display all results in order.
                    foreach (var pair in sorted)
                    {
                        fr.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} = {pair.Value}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I create the list like this

```
static List<string> CreateManufList(List<FilmName> FilmList)
        {
            List<string> stud = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < FilmList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (stud.Contains(FilmList[i].FilmStudio))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    stud.Add(FilmList[i].FilmStudio);
                }
            }
            return stud;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure I'm seeing the problem. [This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UYnwIT) seems to produce the correct result.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your input? Can you show how you create the list you are passing to `GetFrequencies`?

Comment: I added the function that I use to create a list of film studios

Comment: Great, that's exactly where the culprit lies. `stud` will never contain the same name more than once because you `continue` through the `FilmList` instead of adding it to the list if it already exists. Basically you are removing duplicates here.